# when i update the state the result is not updated until i refresh the page by using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

I am working with the dashboard of my academy web app. In dashboard whenever I update or add the course, the state updates but result in the interface only updates until I refresh the page.

```
const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  async function getCoursesServer() {
      const courses = await getCourses();
      setCourses(courses);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCoursesServer();
  }, []);
```

But if I don't use dependency then the error shows up about memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mutating the array while adding course in your "dashboard".

Set a new array while updating courses.

So, in your dashboard, do it like

```js
setCourses([ ...courses, newItem])
```